# Excel: Fetch values from downloaded xml and insert into table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

How do I force Excel to download http://api.eve-central.com/api/evemon, parse it and format the values in a table every time the .xlsx file is opened?

I tried importing the XML and it worked, but I don't know what to do from here.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the problem you're actually trying to solve, maybe there is an easier solution (like a python snippet that outputs a csv file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Data|Import External Query|New Web Query,
there is a param, RefreshOnFileOpen, that you can just set to True.

Here is a snip that gets the data from the net, but doesn't format it (since you said you already got that working).

```
'
'
    Range("I12").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://api.eve-central.com/api/evemon", Destination:=Range("I12"))
        .Name = "evemon_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```